# Fast and efficient algorithm for Phrases Dictionary lookup?

Tags: java, search, tree, lookup

Let's say I have a dictionary with a few million words and phrases. For each input sentence I want to identify (exact match) all words/phrases that the dictionary contains. The longest dictionary name should be preferred and no overlaps. 
For example:

```
Sentence: "Los Angeles Lakers visited Washington State last week"
Dictionary: {Los Angeles, Lakers, Los Angeles Lakers, Washington, State, Washington State University}

Then the sentence would be tagged as follows:
[Los Angeles Lakers] visited [Washington] [State] last week.
```

One solution I can think of is storing the dictionary in memory with constant look-up time (e.g., hash based set) and then extracting all word n-grams from each sentence (n can be set to the number of words in the longest phrase in the dictionary) comparing each against the dictionary and keeping the longest ones that don't overlap. Is there a better solution? (because the n-gram generation can be slow). Maybe trees can help?

Thanks!

Comment: So you decided to go with Los Angeles Lakers over Los Angeles because it was longer. But what makes something longer - letters or words? Consider "The blue sky is superawesome" and you have "The blue sky is" at 4 words and 15 characters, or "sky is superawesome" with only 3 words, but 19 characters. Which would win there?

Comment: And if there is an equal number of words, what criteria would you use then. Longer in characters? Longest word in the token (as in, "A rocket" would win over "This guy")?

Comment: If it's a tie then I don't care which would win. Even random works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to consider something like a [radix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree) or a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), using whole words as part of your buildup. These are the kinds of trees that are natural to dictionary type problems.

Then simply split things into words, and perform a search of the trie. Depending on the expected length of the groupings, you would build from the front (reluctant) or from the back (greedy).

Comment: This might be even better than DAWG. Although requires more space, it looks like it makes it easier to handle white spaces. Could you please  elaborate further on the differences between front and back? Many thanks!

Comment: As in you grab words from the front or back when you parse:
`Los -> Los Angeles -> Los Angeles Lakers`

From the back would be
`Los Angeles Lakers visited Washington State last week -> Los Angeles Lakers visited Washington State last -> Los Angeles Lakers visited Washington State -> etc..`
Essentially I was talking about how you parse the statement to get the groups together.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at [DAWG (Directed acyclic word graph)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acyclic_deterministic_finite_automaton). You would store the whole phrases as paths in DAWG. Then, you would start to match the sentence and find the longest phrase that matches as the longest path. You would then proceed with the rest unmatched sentence similarly. White space would need some special handling.

Comment: <Insert obligatory "Word up, dawg!" joke here>

Comment: @glowcoder DAWG is a good idea; very space efficient. But let's say I have the sentence "State University of Los Angeles" and the dictionary has only two phrase {State University, University of Los Angeles}. Matching from the start would tag the sentence as: "[State University] of Los Angeles" instead of "State [University of Los Angeles]". So I need to think about it. Thanks!

Comment: So maybe I should be removing only one word from the sentence after each match rather than removing the longest string that was matched so far. I think this is what Steven Goldade is referring to in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following code performs non-overlapping tagging of a sentence giving priority to longer matches.

It treats a sentence as an array of string tokens.

It uses a "max_key_size" parameter (maximum size of a key in your dictionary) to avoid searching matches that will never happen.
In your example, the resulting sentence is:

[[Los Angeles Lakers], visited, [Washington], [State], last, week]

Hope it helps:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class NonOverlappingTagging {

    private static ArrayList non_overlapping_tagging(String[] sentence, HashMap dict,int max_key_size) {
        ArrayList tag_sentence = new ArrayList();
        int N = sentence.length;

        if (max_key_size == -1) {
            max_key_size = N;
        }

        int i = 0;

        while (i < N) {

            boolean tagged = false;
            int j = Math.min(i + max_key_size, N); //avoid overflow

            while (j > i) {
                String[] literal_tokens = Arrays.copyOfRange(sentence, i, j);
                String literal = join(literal_tokens, " ");
                System.out.println(literal);

                if (dict.get(literal) != null) {
                    tag_sentence.add("["+literal+"]");
                    i = j;
                    tagged = true;
                }
                else {
                    j -= 1;
                }

            }

            if (!tagged) {
                tag_sentence.add(sentence[i]);
                i += 1;
            }
        }

        return tag_sentence;
    }

    private static String join(String[] sentence, String separator) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length; i++) {
            String word = sentence[i];
            result += word + separator;
        }

        return result.trim();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] sentence = {"Los", "Angeles", "Lakers", "visited", "Washington", "State", "last", "week"};
        HashMap <String, Integer>dict = new HashMap();
        dict.put("Los Angeles", 1);
        dict.put("Lakers", 1);
        dict.put("Los Angeles Lakers", 1);
        dict.put("Washington", 1);
        dict.put("State", 1);
        dict.put("Washington State University", 1);

        ArrayList tagging = non_overlapping_tagging(sentence, dict, -1);

        System.out.println(tagging);    
    }   
}
```